# How to select items from each vector of the list in R

Tags: r

I would like to select the third item from each vector of the list below.
I tried in this way, but I got problems at level 2. I found the function select.list() but I do not know how to apply it. 
Any suggestions? Many thanks.

```
newlist =  x[[1:140]][3]
List of 140
chr(0)
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N11428394 1 
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N10508942 141 
chr(0) 
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N35663 5 
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N12458414 1 
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N5242558 16 
chr [1:7] Brachy leaf N7738408 1 
chr [1:10] Brachy leaf N9826491 633
```

Comment: Interesting - you've had two Answers that assumed two different things. I see your list contains character vectors of various lengths. Do you want the 3rd element of each character vector (as per my answer) or do you want to break each string apart at the spaces and select the 3rd part (as per @Ramnath's answer)?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the code you show, and `x` is the list you want to select *from*, then this will work:

```
lapply(x, FUN = `[`, 3)
```

## Explanation:

`lapply()` takes each component of the supplied list and applies a function to it. In effect it is extracting `x[[1]]` and applying `FUN` to that, then extracting `x[[2]]` and applying `FUN` to it, and so on. So that takes care of this part of your code: `x[[1:140]]`. You just need to do an extract of the 3 element as the `FUN` applied. `` `[` `` is actually a function in R so we can use it as `FUN`. It has to be quoted as it is a special name. The final part is to supply arguments to `` `[`() ``, which we do here using a unnamed argument (the `3` in the function call shown).

## Example:

```
> x <- list(A = letters[1:7], B = letters[1:7], C = letters[1:7])
> (newlist <- lapply(x, `[`, 3))
$A
[1] "c"

$B
[1] "c"

$C
[1] "c"

> 
> ## or as a vector (not a list) result
> (newlist2 <- sapply(x, `[`, 3))
  A   B   C 
"c" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it

```
x = list('Brachy leaf N11428394 1', 
        'Brachy leaf N10508942 141', 
        'Brachy leaf N356635')
sapply(sapply(x, strsplit, split = " "), '[', 3)
```

This gives

```
[1] "N11428394" "N10508942" "N356635"
```